# Node.js Socket.io Chat-example not work

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I just start with node.js, i install node on my hosting, add some plugins and i download socket.io sample chat from

> https://github.com/socketio/chat-example.git

when i run it (node index.js) i get alert on console "listening on *:3000" and it looks like everything will work, but when i go to my site on port 3000 ( coracko.com:3000 ) chat is visible but the message does not send and nothing happen.

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
      #messages { margin-bottom: 40px }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
   $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        $('form').submit(function(){
          socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
          $('#m').val('');
          return false;
        });
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
          $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
          window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        });
      });
});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

if it matters script is running for now on coracko.com:3000

Comment: Your exact code works for me on my computer.  You will have to debug the issue.  I added `console.log()` statements in all the event handlers to see what was happening and when.  You can either do that or put breakpoints in the debugger in every event handler.  If you get the web page showing in your browser, then it is clear that the server is started and port 3000 is working so at that point, you have to see if your form submit handler is getting called and see if your server receives the incoming socket.io connection or message and look for console messages in both browser and server.

Comment: It is possible that your hosting does not support socket.io connections or does not support them on port 3000.  Could also try port 80.  Could also search your hosting docs for webSocket/socket.io info.

Comment: Can you use inspect and check for the errors logged in the console? I speculate that you do not include [socket.io.js.map](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js.map).